# Why does InDesign put "c_" before literal text?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm working with the old interchange format of Adobe InDesign (`.inx` files).

This XML file has text contents like the following:

```
<pcnt>c_Stackoverflow&#13;&#13;</pcnt>
```

Which results in

```
Stackoverflow<CR><CR>
```

Question: Why does it put `c_` before the actual value and not simply use `CDATA` in doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe has been encoding *everything*.

The reason they prefix the payload is because you can have several values in a single field, hence, CDATA would not be working.

`c_` indicates a string

`x_` represents a list (enum)

`x_a` represents a list with 0x0a items (a = 10 hexadecimal)

`l_` represents a long

See a full list of all prefixes in the PDF:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/indesign/sdk/working_with_inx_file_format.pdf